# Azure App Service SFTP outbound error An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, sftp, azure-webjobs, ssh.net

I have an Azure App that uploads files to another server through SFTP (port 22) using SSH.NET. I confirmed that everything works fine on my local machine, but after deploying to Azure App Service and when trying to connect to the SFTP server from the app, I get this error message.

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

I made sure that the SFTP server accepts all the Azure App Service outbound IP addresses, and I do not have any outbound rules set up on the Azure App Service.

I thought this could be my service plan issue, so I upgraded the App service plan to S1 from the free plan, but still no luck.

I tried connecting to the SFTP server with Kudu, but it is working.

[image]

So...it is not the rule issue? I'm lost.

Any ideas why the SFTP connection is not working from Azure App Service?